# Send json parms in a post request in Flask API python getting errror ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")

Tags: python, json, mongodb, api, flask

I'm developing a Flask API. I want to create an API route that with accept JSON parameters and based on that json to do a search in database.
My code looks like this:

```
@mod_api.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def test():
    query_params = json.loads(request.data)
    json_resp = mongo.db.mydb.find(query_params)
    return Response(response=json_util.dumps(json_resp), status=200, mimetype='application/json')
```

Now when I run the api i go to my route: This example looks like this:

```
http://0.0.0.0:5002/api/test
```

I don't know exactly how to send a json parameter. If i do like this:

```
http://0.0.0.0:5002/api/test?{'var1':'123', 'var2':'456'}
```

I get an error `ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")`

How to send this json parameter?

Comment: JSON means data in request body, not parameters in url.

Comment: @furas thank you for your answer? Can you explain it more please?

Comment: first print `request.data` to see what you get. maybe you should use `test?args="{'var1':'123', 'var2':'456'}"` or `test?var1=123&var2=456` to get correct  values in `request.data`.

Answer (score 1):

You likely aren't supplying JSON data. With your browser at http://0.0.0.0:5002, use XHR in the browser console to test out your API.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   // new HttpRequest instance 
xmlhttp.open("POST", "/api/test");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify({'var1':'123', 'var2':'456'}));
```

You can see the request/response in the Network tab, and the Flask process will show the request happening as well.

Answer (score 0):

First, I want to point out that usually we use [`request.get_json()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#flask.Request.get_json) to get the json data, [`request.data`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#flask.Request.data) contains the incoming request data that flask can't handle.

Test your app with `curl` should be easy, send the json data this way:

```
$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"var1":"123", "var2":"456"}' http://localhost:5000/api/test
```